# Migrate Custom metadata type

Tags: metadata-api, metadata, custom-metadata, list-metadata

I need to migrate Custom Metadata type using a `package.xml`.

Can someone please let me know what should I put to get the metadata along with data successfully get migrated? Suppose Custom Metadata type name is `Call_Duration_Zip_abv__mdt`.

Comment: Why not use Change set for this.This is one of the best feature of suing Custom metadata type

Comment: No our client deliberately needs package . xml :(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the Document

> A custom metadata type is defined as a custom object and is stored in
>   the objects folder. Custom metadata types have a suffix of `__mdt`
>   (instead of `__c` for custom objects). Custom metadata type field
>   names have a suffix of `__c`, like other custom fields. Custom
>   metadata type field names must be dot-qualified with the name of the
>   custom metadata type to which they belong.

This excerpt from a `package.xml` file shows the use of dot notation and the __mdt suffix. If you’re using a namespace, for example `picklist1234`,​ the full name of `ReusablePicklistOption__mdt` would be `picklist1234`​`__ReusablePicklistOption__mdt`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Package xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
...
   <types>
      <members>PicklistTest__c.PicklistTestField__c</members>
      <members>ReusablePicklistOption__mdt.Picklist__c</members>
      <members>ReusablePicklistOption__mdt.SortOrder__c</members>
      <members>PicklistUsage__mdt.Field__c</members>
      <members>PicklistUsage__mdt.Picklist__c</members>
      <members>PicklistUsage__mdt.SObjectType__c</members>
      <members>ReusablePicklist__mdt.AlphaSort__c</members>
      <name>CustomField</name>
   </types>
...
   <types>
      <members>PicklistTest__c</members>
      <members>ReusablePicklistOption__mdt</members>
      <members>PicklistUsage__mdt</members>
      <members>ReusablePicklist__mdt</members>
      <name>CustomObject</name>
   </types>
...
   <version>39.0</version>
</Package>
```

Go through [this](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_custommetadatatypes.htm)  if you need more information.
Let us know if this works for you or not.

Comment: Gotta love the Metadata API docs. That's always my first step when I need to figure out how to deploy something new via ANT.